# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: oracle, jpa

While saving an object in database , I am getting below error:

2016-10-13 05:05:59.152 ERROR 4596 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00932: **inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY**

2016-10-13 05:05:59.156  INFO 4596 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-10-13 05:05:59.184 ERROR 4596 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[servletContainer]     : Servlet.service() for servlet [servletContainer] in context with path [] threw exception [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

I have Boolean fields in my entity as follows:

```
private Boolean isAccount;
private Boolean isEnabled;
```

and in Oracle db , these fields' types are Number. 
When I am saving using JPA repository , using below code

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.setIsAccount(false);
contact.setIsEnabled(false);
contactDao.save(contact);
```

It is throwing above error. Oracle should automatically convert Boolean to Number. Then why I am getting inconsistent datatype error? Anybody plz suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Here I am using 2 dbs , first db to get contact and then update existing contact(if any) in 2nd db or create new one. Does that can cause this issue?

Comment: Thanks, i resolved . Mistakenly i was using wrong type for one of the column in Entity.